# Slow compound mysql update query

Tags: mysql

We're doing an update query between two database tables and it is ridiculously slow. As in: it would take 30 *days* to perform the query.

One table, lab.list, contains about 940,000 records, the other, mind.list about 3,700,000 (3.7 million)
The update sets a field when two BETWEEN conditions are met. This is the query:

```
UPDATE lab.list L , mind.list M SET L.locId = M.locId  WHERE L.longip BETWEEN M.startIpNum AND M.endIpNum AND L.date BETWEEN "20100301" AND "20100401" AND L.locId = 0
```

As it is now, the query is performing with about 1 update every 8 seconds.

We also tried it with the mind.list table in the same database, but that doesn't matter for the query time.

```
UPDATE lab.list L, lab.mind M  SET L.locId = M.locId  WHERE  longip BETWEEN M.startIpNum AND M.endIpNum AND date BETWEEN "20100301" AND "20100401" AND L.locId = 0;
```

Is there a way to speed up this query? Basically IMHO it should make two subsets of the databases:
mind.list.longip BETWEEN M.startIpNum AND M.endIpNum
lab.list.date BETWEEN "20100301" AND "20100401"

and then update the values for these subsets. Somewhere along the line I think I made a mistake, but where? Maybe there is a faster query possible?

We tried log_slow_queries, but that shows that it is indeed examining 100s of millions of rows, probably going up all the way to 3331 gigarows.

Tech info:

- Server version: 5.5.22-0ubuntu1-log (Ubuntu)
- lab.list has indexes on locId, longip, date
- lab.mind has indexes on locId, startIpNum AND M.endIpNum
- hardware: 2x xeon 3.4 GHz, 4GB RAM, 128 GB SSD (so that should not be a problem!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the query was too big or cumbersome for mysql to fill. Even after indexing. Testing the same query with the same data on a high-end Sybase server, also took 3 hours.

So we abandoned the *do it all on the database server* thought, and went back to scripting languages.

We did the following in python:

1. load a chunk of 100000 records of the 3.7 million records, and loop over the rows
2. for each row, set the locId and fill in the rest of the columns

All these updates together take about 5 minutes, so a huge improvement!

Conclusion:

> think outside of the database box!

Answer (score 1):

I would first of all try to index mind on startIpNum, endIpNum, locId in this order. locId is not used in SELECTing from mind, even if it is used for the update.

For the same reason I'd index lab on locId, date and longip (which isn't used in the first chunking, which should run on date) this order.

Then what kind of datatype is assigned to startIpNum and endIpNum? For IPv4, it's best to convert to INTEGER and use INET_ATON and INET_NTOA for user I/O. I assume you already did this.

To run the update, you might try to segment the M database using temporary tables. That is:

```
* select all records of lab in the given range of dates with locId = 0 into a temporary table TABLE1.
* run an analysis on TABLE1 grouping IP addresses by their first N bits (using AND with a suitable mask: 0x80000000, 0xC0000000, ... 0xF8000000... and so on, until you find  that you have divided into a "suitable" number of IP "families". These will, by and large, match with startIpNum (but that's not strictly necessary).
* say that you have divided in 1000 families of IP.
* For each family:
*    select those IPs from TABLE1 to TABLE3.
*    select the IPs matching that family from mind to TABLE2.
*    run the update of the matching records between TABLE3 and TABLE2. This should take place in about one hundred thousandth of the time of the big query.
*    copy-update TABLE3 into lab, discard TABLE3 and TABLE2.
* Repeat with next "family".
```

It is not really ideal, but if the slightly improved indexing does not help, I really don't see all that many options.

Comment: Hi Isemi,
Thanks for your thoughts. startIpNum and endIpNum are indeed ints, but currently they are bigints (11 bytes). We will try your other ideas, especially the chunking, later today. Although a different query where we select first and insert them in a new, clean table, was also dead slow. 
We are beginning to suspect more serious system problems, as deleting the old index also takes 10 minutes now...